# What weapon is Argent Squire holding?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, hearthstone

In *HearthStone: Heroes of Warcraft*, Argent Squire is wearing Tier 7 paladin gear and holding a weapon from World of Warcraft.  I thought it was a Naxxramas weapon like the gear but I am unable to identify it.

[image: Argent Squire card from Hearthstone]

What weapon is the Argent Squire holding?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's the *[Torch of Holy Fire](http://www.wowhead.com/item=40395/torch-of-holy-fire)* from Naxxramas / Kel'Thuzad.
So you were right with your guess.

[image: Weapon] [image: equipped Weapon]

Comment: That is it.  Good find. I must of missed it because the item thumbnail looks so different.